# JavaFX project on IDEA runs well, but exe file doen't work properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-8, exe, telegram-bot

**JavaFX TelegramBots API**

I have been working on a JavaFX project which uses 
**telegrambots-2.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.**

It has two buttons:

1) Start btn – calls HandleTelegramBot method 
from TelegramManager class 
and sets text in textField1

2) Test app btn – sets text in textField2

It is running very good on **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5**.
The issue is if I build exe file only “Test app btn” is working.
“Start btn” which should launch **Telegram Bot**   is not working.
No idea what is a problem.
Please give your opinion if you are similar with such a situation.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    primaryStage.setTitle("TelegramBot");
    Button startBtn = new Button("Start btn");
    Button testBtn = new Button("Test app btn");
    TextField txt = new TextField();
    TextField txtTest = new TextField();
    //Object from telegram Manager class
    TelegramManager telegramManager = new TelegramManager();
    //Buttons onAction
    startBtn.setOnAction(e-> {telegramManager.HandleTelegramMethod();
        txt.setText("Bot is working"); });
    testBtn.setOnAction(e->{
        txtTest.setText("exe file is working"); });

    //layout
    VBox layout = new VBox();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(startBtn, txt, testBtn, txtTest);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pim1T.jpg)

Comment: How are you creating the exe-file?

Comment: With IDEA build artifacts